# Store current background-image in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a light weight carousel on my clients site. The current issue is that it is not storing the original background-image of the div. How would i go about adding this to what i currently have? I will keep trying but so far i am not able to get the original image to show through out the swapping of images.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-<?php echo $id?>" id="wrapper-top" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $hero_img[0];?>);">

    <script>
function heroSlider (){
  jQuery(window).on('load', function () {
    (function ($) {
      "use strict";
      $.noConflict();
                $(function() {
                var homeCarousel = $('#wrapper-top');

                var backgrounds = [];

                for(var i=0; i<6; i++){

                    if($('#slide-'+i).text().trim().length != 0){

                        backgrounds.push('url('+ $('#slide-'+i).text() +')');

                    }

                }

                var current = 0;

                function nextBackground() {
                homeCarousel.css(
                 'background-image',
                    backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]
                );

                setTimeout(nextBackground, 10000);
                }
                setTimeout(nextBackground, 10000).delay(3000);
                 homeCarousel.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
                });
        })(jQuery);
  });
}
heroSlider();
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain better what you want to happen?

Comment: Can you show us the `#slide-1`, `#slide-2`... divs?

Comment: you need to add a slide with the first background on and start with that shown, it is not added to your array as it is currently on the wrapper and not a slide (and you only loop through the slides)

Comment: Pete - you are correct. How would i do that? Something like this and then add it to the slide-* This is where i get lost.

`var currentBg = $('#wrapper-top').css('background-image');`